# Foreach loop filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I am getting familiar with an SSIS solution and I just realized something that is new for me:

there is a foreach loop task which contains this information in the "Files:" box:

[image]

What does it mean?

Does it mean that the task will take the files with name like:

`A(something)Sell(something)Depot(something).csv`?

like: **A10Sell123Depot21.csv**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Files text box,  The asterisk wildcard (*) mean that you don't know this part of the name.

```
`*` --> unknown string
`?` --> unknown character
```

**Example:**

*"In the Files text box, enter File*.txt. The asterisk wildcard (*) let’s us include any text file that starts with “File,” without having to specify each file. If our files had instead been Word files, we would have entered File*.doc. If we were moving multiple file types, we would have used File*.* as our property value." *[Read More](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/)*

So in your case, yes `A*Sell*Depot*.csv` means `A(something)Sell(something)Depot(something).csv` which will match `A10Sell123Depot21.csv`